# Why is my curious badge not being awarded?

Tags: support, badge-progress

I just looked at my meta profile, and saw this in the badge tracker:

[image]

Usually, when I meet the badge requirements, the badge disappears from tracker.

Whats going on here?

Nowhere does it say that I earned the badge.

[image]

Comment: There's another requirement for it: having positive question record. Click the description, it says you don't have it.

Comment: @DanielStorm not actually a duplicate, the causes are different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Curious, Inquisitive and Socratic has two requirements:

- Ask a well-received question on X separate days, and
- **maintain a positive question record**

You lack the last one.

[image]